# React onClick event not working as expected inside loop

Tags: reactjs

This is my code,

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const categories = [
    { name: "aaa", slug: "aaa" },
    { name: "baa", slug: "baa" }
  ];

  const handleClick = (value) => {
    console.log(value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <div>
        <ul>
          {categories.map((category) => (
            <li className="cat_item" key={category.slug}>
              <a
                value="value"
                onClick={(e) => handleClick(e.currentTarget.value)}
                className="dropdown-item"
              >
                {category.name}
                <span className="text-gray-25 font-size-12 font-weight-normal"></span>
              </a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But whn I click it **appear as undefined instead of value** in log. Here is a [fiddle of issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-violet-1w9x0m)

Comment: use `e.target.value` instead

Comment: Thanks. Tried but still the same unfotunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the target is the HTML anchor element itself and thus doesn't have a value property associated with it. In your case, I'm assuming you want to get the text within the your anchort element, try this instead.

```
onClick={(e) => handleClick(e.target.textContent)}
```

And we can use this for custom attributes,

```
onClick={(e) => handleClick(e.target.attributes.getNamedItem("value").value)}
```

Source is [here](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-access-custom-attributes-from-aevent-object-in-react)

Answer (score 2):

you have try to pass the value. But here no any input field that's why undefined here. You have try to pass innerText content.

```
onClick={(e) => handleClick(e.currentTarget.innerText)}
```